# How to "inject" NuGet package in Jenkins CI build job

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

So here is the case: We have a web application which can be deployed for different customers. The web application can be extended by different modules per customer. The modules are created as NuGet packages and contain the DLLs together with static files like e.g. HTML, CSS, JS, ASMX...

As not all customers use the same modules and the base web application shall be as sleek as possible, the web application project itself doesn't know anything about the modules. Instead a Jenkins build job is available for each customer. In this build job the packages.config file will be modified to add the NuGet package entry for the wanted module. Then we do a `nuget.exe restore` and a `nuget.exe update` (to ensure it's on the latest version) for the module NuGet package. After this we use msbuild and Octopack to build and deploy the web application.

All of this works great for the DLLs included in the modules NuGet package and for the web.config transformations (done via web.config.install.xdt), but unfortunately it doesn't work for the static files included in the modules NuGet package :(

I assume that this is the case due to the missing references in the web applications .csproj file!? So the static files are actually copied to the correct locations, but are not added to the final Octopack Nuget package as they are not recognized as project content.

As far as I have researched till now this is nothing we can solve using the NuGet CLI itself, but are there any other options maybe? The Package Manager Console is only available within the powershell context of Visual Studio, right? (`Update-Package -Reinstall` would be perfect I guess)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the following solution (Octopack to win!). Instead of relying solely on NuGet, we use an option provided by Octopack which is `OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles=true`. This tells Octopack to not only add the project files to the resulting NuGet package (as it would normally do), but on top of this add files/folders listed in the `<files>` section defined in a .nuspec file you added to the project. See: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack#UsingOctoPack-IncludingadditionalfilesusingaNuSpecfile(.nuspec)

So our base project only has the nuspec file with an empty `<files>` section. The module then includes XDT files to tranform the nuspec file on (un)install to configure the additional files/folders which shall be added by Octopack. This way they don't have to be part of the csproj file.

I would love to see this option to handle the `<files>` section as an inclusive list of additional files (instead of either csproj or `files` section) be added to the nuget cli as well.